Blazor .NET 8 or 9 - Error HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync QuicTransportOptions
I get 100+ of these errors none stop on my Blazor Server. I don't know where to begin to find this error. Debug is showing no issues, server app runs with zero issues for weeks. But I keep getting these errors none stop.

2024-09-12 20:52:56.705 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:52:59.058 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:53:06.262 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:53:07.864 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:53:09.085 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:53:42.395 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicStreamContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3ControlStream.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException abortReason, Http3ErrorCode errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:53:44.139 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:53:51.254 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:53:52.382 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:55:59.012 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:56:19.442 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:56:34.797 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:56:35.263 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:57:03.573 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:57:26.934 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)
2024-09-12 20:58:09.536 -07:00 [FTL] Unexpected exception in HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A value between 0x0 and 0x3fffffffffffffff is required. (Parameter 'errorCode')
Actual value was -1.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions.ValidateErrorCode(Int64 errorCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.Internal.QuicConnectionContext.set_Error(Int64 value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.Abort(ConnectionAbortedException ex, Http3ErrorCode errorCode, ConnectionEndReason reason)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http3.Http3Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication1 httpApplication)

Get help on identifying these errors.

This is related with the QUIC transport. You could check this OUIC configuration to make sure it is right or not. Or disable the http3 to see if this error will change or not.

I didnt change any settings with QUIC. Using default settings in Blazor. Is there a way to configure QUIC in blazor?
